# "onchange" event delayed in IE? (ok with Firefox)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, dom-events

It might be a beginner question but I can't understand why the `onchange` event is never called by IE while it works Ok with Firefox.

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" size="48" value="" onchange="execute()"/>
<button type="button" onclick="execute()">Go</button>
```

The execute function is called when the button is clicked but not when the text in the input box is changed.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look there : http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B319741&x=11&y=12 it seems that the onchange event has a bug

Comment: Use a cross-browser framework or else you ain't finished finding quirks...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IE only fires the `onchange` event when the element loses focus - if you were to click outside the element or tab to a different element it should fire then.

You can get around this by using a different event, for example `onkeypress`.

Comment: Sure that only IE shows this behaviour? I just tested it in FF3.5 and IE7 - both show the same behaviour i.e. both fire the event after losing focus.

Comment: After some tries, I've to admit that this is the best answer. jquery have a similar issue with IE. I had to use keydown event rather than onchange.

Comment: As usual, reading the specs is a good place to start: *"The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus."* - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use both `onkeypress` and `onchange` since the field can be modified with right click+paste as well.

Comment: This is only true if the menu is open. Firefox and IE differ when the menu is focused but isn't actually open, say for a keyboard user (via tab + arrows). In this instance, Firefox does not fire onchange until the element loses focus, while IE does fire when arrowing through the options. Totally different behavior when the menu is actually open (via Alt + down arrow, including screen reader behavior).

Answer (score 6):

While annoying, it is **not a bug** that `onchange` is not fired *until* the element loses focus. (I get around the issue by having multiple bindings for different events; make sure not to clobber a handler and use an update aggregation if appropriate.)

Here is the ["official" W3C documentation on the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3):

> The onchange event occurs *when a control loses the input focus* and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This attribute applies to the following elements: INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Here is the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> This event is *fired when the contents are committed* and not while the value is changing. For example, on a text box, this event is not fired while the user is typing, but rather *[it is fired] when the user commits the change by leaving the text box that has focus*.

The behavior, while often annoying, is *as specified*.

Answer (score 3):

As answered elsewhere, IE doesn't fire the event till you click outside the input field.

Just a quick expaination of how I fixed it with jQuery. (This is a translation of my code, so it may contain bugs...)

```
<input id="somecheck" name="somecheck" value="1" onchange="dosomething();">
```

...was changed to...

```
<input id="somecheck" name="somecheck" value="1">

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#somecheck').change(function() { dosomething(); } );
});
</script>
```

For those new to jQuery you are basically waiting for the page to become fully loaded, then you are adding the event handler 'dosomething' to the input box.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i remember, IE doesn't handle onchange event the same maner as FF.
The event will be fired when the mouse is clicked.

I advise you to use a library to handle events such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), etc..

Comment: You are right! and I will follow your advice and use jquery for that

Comment: jQuery is a good recommendation but it has a similar issue with onchange and IE

Comment: Could you post your code ? I did recently a similar thing to handle two select inputs and had no problems.

Answer (score 2):

ohhh, I spent some time on that issue as well months ago.
I came up with this solution for FF/IE onchange

```
$("input[name*='delivery_method']").bind(($.browser.msie ? "click" : "change"), function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does it after your input loses focus, which isn't until you click the button, tab out, or click somewhere else on the screen. Try onclick or one of the other events.