# window.onchange = function() event

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that shows/hides different messages according to a combination of select dropdowns that works fine in chrome and FF using the window.onchange event. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work in ie and if they have a solution please.

It had to be built in tables due to internal restriction.

```
    ;(function(){
    document.onchange = function(){
        // Initialise variables for drop down options
        var homeMove        = document.getElementById('homeMove'),
            transferOrder   = document.getElementById('transferOrder'),
            orderComplete   = document.getElementById('orderComplete'),
            submitBtn       = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

        // Initialise variables for comments
        var comment1 = document.getElementById('comment1'),
            comment2 = document.getElementById('comment2'),
            comment3 = document.getElementById('comment3');


        if((homeMove.value == 'No') && (transferOrder.value == 'No')){
            comment2.style.display = 'none';
            comment3.style.display = 'none';
            comment1.style.display = 'block';
            submitBtn.disabled = true;
        }   

        // if Home Move - No AND Transfer Order - Yes. Display nothing. Submit button abled
        if((homeMove.value == 'No') && (transferOrder.value == 'Yes')){
            comment1.style.display = 'none';
            comment2.style.display = 'none';
            comment3.style.display = 'none';
            submitBtn.disabled = false;
        }

        // If Home Move - Yes AND Transfer Order - NO. Display comment1. Submit button disables
        if((homeMove.value == 'Yes') && (transferOrder.value == 'No')){
            comment1.style.display = 'block';
            comment2.style.display = 'none';
            comment3.style.display = 'none';
            submitBtn.disabled = true;
        }

        // If Home Move - Yes AND Transfer Order - Yes AND Order Complete - Yes. Display comment2 Subhmit button abled
        if((homeMove.value == 'Yes') && (transferOrder.value == 'Yes') && (orderComplete.value == 'Yes')){
            comment1.style.display = 'none';
            comment2.style.display = 'block';
            comment3.style.display = 'none';
            submitBtn.disabled = false;
        }   

        // If Home Move - Yes AND Transfer Order - Yes and Order Complete - No. Display comment3. Submit button disabled
        if((homeMove.value == 'Yes') && (transferOrder.value == 'Yes') && (orderComplete.value == 'No')){
            comment1.style.display = 'none';
            comment2.style.display = 'none';
            comment3.style.display = 'block';
            submitBtn.disabled = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

Any help with this would be great. Thanks

Comment: perhaps [this thread on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594700/onchange-event-delayed-in-ie-ok-with-firefox) explains it and solves your problem

Comment: I would move the `var` declarations above the `document.onchange()` but still inside the anonymous function, unless the elements can disappear from the DOM of course ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would be better if instead of doing a document.change, add events to change of drop downs.

Sometimes onpropertychange is a more sure shot event to rely on for ie. but make sure for that event, you do a subsequent check that the event is for a change in value by adding the following filter:

```
yourselectboxelement.onpropertychange = function() { 
  if (window.event.propertyName == "value") {   
   // Do stuff here     
  } 
};
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, Not too sure what you mean when you say to use window.event.propertyName. could you clarify please. 

My HTML is using 3 select tags with different ID's and the event should fire when a different combination of YES/NO from each dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code. Take a look. You can add this event for all the 3 select tags. Inside where I have "Do stuff here", you can check if values have changed. See if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

IE only fires the onchange event when the element loses focus

Try to use onclick event.